# Can Gson and Jackson annotations coexist in the same POJO?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, gson

I'm working on a legacy Android project which uses a very old version of Jackson lib to parse JSONs brought from our web API.

I am currently working on a new feature for said project, and would like to use Retrofit with Gson lib as its JSON parser, since both libs provide more flexibility and a cleaner code if compared to our previous lib choices.

Problem is, I will need some of the legacy POJOs, and those already have Jackson annotations. Does putting Gson and Jackson annotations in the same class generate any conflicts? Or will I be forced to create mirror classes with Gson annotations in order to avoid potential issues?

Example:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class someClass {

    @JsonProperty ("some_attribute") // Jackson annotation
    @SerializedName("some_attribute") // Gson annotation
    private String someAttribute;

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Annotations are just metadata. They don't have any behavior on their own.

What does have behavior is the corresponding component that processes the annotation. For example, Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (its internals) reads the type you provide, introspects it to find any **meaningful** annotations, and uses them to serialize/deserialize. `@SerializedName` isn't meaningful to Jackson, so it ignores it. Similarly, `@JsonProperty` isn't meaningful to Gson, so it ignores it.

There won't be any issues*.

<sub>* Unless you write your own type adapters that for whatever reason use another library's annotations.</sub>